# How to block overriding variables by extra_vars in Ansible?

Tags: security, ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I am using Ansible Tower to expose play. User stars job calling REST API and she/he provides some extra_vars. I have to validate provided variable against some other variables. For example: user provides hostname and I have in the inventory variable: allowed_hostnames. 
Problem is extra_vars trumps everything, so user can always override variable for list of allowed values, and test does not make sense. 
In Tower there is a Survey feature that can be used to limit variables allowed to change by user, but enabling Survey will block dict variables and I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Problem is extra_vars trumps everything"*

A: Avoid variable. For example the task

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_host|default('') }} is allowed to ..."
  when: "my_host|default('') in  lookup('file', 'allowed_hosts.yml')|from_yaml"
```

with the data

```
$ cat allowed_hosts.yml
  - host1
  - host2
  - host3
  - host9
```

gives

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml -e 'my_host=host2'

    "msg": "host2 is allowed to ..."
```

---

Next options might be *pipe, redis, modgodb ...* lookup [plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#plugin-list),  custom filter, or custom lookup [plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#plugin-guidelines).

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Vladimir answer I have done this like that:

```
- name: Check variables
  fail:
  when: "{{ {'restricted_variables':restricted_variables} != lookup('file', 'restricted_variables.yml')|from_yaml }}"
```

where `restricted_variables.yml`:

```
restricted_variables:
  variable1: somevalue
  variable2:
    var1: 1
    var2: 2
```